# Cloudflare not hiding the host

Tags: cloudflare

I proxied the domain.

In https://hostingchecker.com/ cloudflare hide my site(blog.webjeda.com) host.

But [here](https://whatcms.org/?s=blog.webjeda.com) It is not hiding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was likely a TTL / delay when you updated your DNS records to Cloudflare. Both tools now show Cloudflare as your host.

Comment: But it reveals host [here](https://i.ibb.co/LrqFBg3/Screenshot-2.png)

Comment: Out of the box, the idea of Cloudflare is to mask your specific Origin server / IP Address. What content management system you use, or if you use Github pages, is discernable from the source code (HTML) of the page, HTTP headers, etc.

Comment: I uploaded the same code in gitlab, but it cannot reveal my host. Can you please tell me which code reveals that the script is hosted in github?